# Any workarounds for structs failing to cast to object when the struct is the covariant type of a generic object being being casted in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, struct, casting, covariance

Say I instantiate a generic class with a covariant type parameter which is a `struct`, then I cast the newly created object as itself with a type parameter of `object` in the place of `struct`, the cast will fail though the variance should allow for it.

Example:

```
public class Succeeds {}
public struct Fails {}

var castSucceeds = (IEnumerable<object>)Enumerable.Empty<Succeeds>();
var castFails = (IEnumerable<object>)Enumerable.Empty<Fails>();
```

As you can see from the above this cast works thanks to the generic type of `IEnumerable<T>` being covariant, but when attempted with a `struct` instead of a `class` it fails. I suspect the failure is related to the need for boxing when casting a struct to an object.

Is there any way around this or am I perhaps looking at it wrong?

Comment: As docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance) say: Variance applies only to reference types; if you specify a value type for a variant type parameter, that type parameter is invariant for the resulting constructed type.

Comment: Variance doesn't apply for obvious reasons: an unboxed valuetype and a class have completely different layouts. The unboxed valuetype doesn't actually implement the interface, only the boxed version does. There are special optimizations for generics to avoid the boxing, but then internally it ends up being a direct method call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance):

> Variance applies only to reference types; if you specify a value type
> for a variant type parameter, that type parameter is invariant for the
> resulting constructed type.

Try doing a manual cast:

```
var castFails = Enumerable.Empty<Fails>().Cast<object>();
```

Comment: Thanks, I definitely missed that when trying to figure out where I was going wrong!

Comment: The manual cast example won't work for me as I'm not actually dealing with an `IEnumerable`